As a landlord in Texas, can I request a tenant to troubleshoot something before spending to fix it?
I'm a landlord in Texas and I was just told by my property manager that the tenant said the garbage disposal needs to be replaced.
My property manager, without doing any research or investigating, asked if I could dispatch a plumber to fix/replace it.
I wanted to do some troubleshooting first because a garbage disposal can be easily fixed by resetting it and manually turning the motor under the sink. I've done this several times when I used to live at that property and I think it's not a big deal to ask of my tenant to do this.
In the past, it's happened where I was told that I had to replace something but it turned out that all that was wrong was the switch was off, as an example.
Is this legal to do? And is this smart to do? I obviously want to save money but I want to avoid getting in some kind of legal hot water here.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Unless your lease with the renter specifies that the tenant may be called on to do some forms of maintenance, then you or your agent has to do the troubleshooting. Without language about that, the lease obligates the tenant to pay the specified amount each month and obligates you to provide working fixtures. What you are suggesting seems pretty minimal, and the tenant might agree to it as a convenience to get it fixed more quickly. But if they say 'no', then it's on you.
If it was me I wouldn't dream of asking a tenant to do this, simply as a practical matter. You likely don't have any idea of how competent they are around electrical and mechanical stuff, and they could seriously injure themselves. Presumably you do have some confidence in the mechanical and electrical skills of your property manager. You do not want your manager calling you to say "Hey boss, I found the tenant lying in the kitchen in a pool of water, apparently electrocuted and with their hand turned to hamburger."

Would I really be liable if I asked the tenant to simply press a reset button and wiggle free the motor via a wrench and they injure themselves? I'm not forcing them to do this, they can say no but I'd prefer not spending hundreds of dollars all to find out that nothing's wrong.

@TiramisuOho remember that you may incur costs defending yourself even if you are not liable.  Also consider the personal consequences auch as guilt or shame if the tenant is injured while following your instructions, or the possibility that the tenant further damages the disposal or the plumbing by doing something wrong with the wrench.  If I were in your shoes I would probably call the tenant to discuss it, saying that I would prefer to avoid paying for a plumber if possible, and see what the tenant (and you!) are comfortable with the tenant doing.

@TiramisuOho but one of the costs of doing business is having to hire professionals for work like this that you otherwise might be able to do yourself.  This is especially true if you aren't near the property, which I assume to be the case because if you were you would be able to arrange with the tenant's consent to look at the disposal yourself, but in that case you probably wouldn't be asking the question.

Charles E. Grant: the lead of this answer implies that the landlord can't ask the tenant to do the troubleshooting. The end of the paragraph acknowledges that it is acceptable to ask (and correctly notes that under typical lease terms the tenant could refuse), but it might be better to rephrase the first sentence to avoid the absolute-sounding statement "you or your agent has to do the troubleshooting."

@TiramisuOho from a different (technical/safety) perspective there's a big difference between pressing a reset button, a normal user task, and something requiring tools (which, BTW, it's probably not reasonable to expect a tenant to even have). I'd hope the property manager could press a simple button, but they may not have been physically present

"Would I really be liable if I asked the tenant to simply press a reset button and wiggle free the motor via a wrench and they injure themselves?" Possibly. You're their landlord and you owe them a working garbage disposal, and you directed them to do it, so you might have a higher duty of care than say, their uncle or a random person they met on the bus. By the way, I hope you are unplugging the power to the disposal before you start wiggling the motor with a wrench.

@phoog I was trying to emphasize that baring other language, fixing the disposal is a contractual obligation of the OP. For small things people may informally wave their rights, but they certainly don't have to.

@ChrisH For the specific example of turning a garbage disposal motor, the tool in question is usually provided as part of the same package with the garbage disposal itself, because garbage disposals are specifically designed to enable even amateurs to do this operation safely and easily just by following the instruction manual. It's an Allen wrench, and all you have to do is stick it in a slot on the outside bottom of the disposal and use it to rotate the slot.

@Douglas that's an interesting middle ground. With products I've been involved in designing (industrial rather than consumer), using a provided tool for simple maintenance would be a user task requiring a little training -  perhaps just instructions, but for users with enough background training to follow those instructions correctly. Again, thinking technically, and assuming an inexperienced tenant, someone going in to troubleshoot, check the tool and instructions are present and correct, and demonstrate, would seem like a reasonable action. A tenant may have have picked up any tool before.

Here's a comparable example:
I once complained to my landlord's agent that an appliance wasn't working.  They sent an electrician, who came and looked at it, pressed some buttons, and everything was working.
They sent a bill to the agent, who forwarded it to me and told me I had to pay it because nothing was wrong with the appliance.
I told them to get lost, quite fairly I think.  This was because there was no reasonable way that I could have know the magic combination of cryptically labelled buttons to press.
However, if they had said to me "the instructions were left in the drawer right next to the appliance" then I think it would have been quite reasonable for them to expect me to pay the unnecessary bill, and to deduct it from my deposit if I refused.
So my answer is really, you should expect them to do something if it is what the manufacturer of the equipment would expect the end user to do, as shown by the instructions.  This also at least partially helps shift the liability to the manufacturer if something goes wrong.

For turning a garbage disposal motor, I believe manufacturers do expect end users to do it, as evidenced by the fact that most garbage disposals come with the needed tool (an Allen wrench) as part of the package.

It's not a legal answer, but it's worth thinking of the worst case scenario here, who is liable, and how this plays out if something goes wrong.
In this case, what happens if:

The tenant, while following your instructions, drops whatever they were turning the motor with directly into the garbage disposal by mistake, damaging it. As a tenant, I'd not want to find out if me or the landlord is liable for a clumsy slip of whatever I was using to turn the motor, so I'd refuse without something written saying I'm not responsible for damage.

There's a loose wire in the casing, and I electrocute myself while following your instructions. Presumably, someone will sue you. And that's going to be a complicated, expensive case.


Now, if some general purpose handyman sticks a pipe wrench down the garbage disposal, killing himself and trashing the machine, it's a lot more neatly handled. Presumably, he has insurance. There was an assumption of competence on his part, assuming nothing was obviously dangerous. There's still possibly a lawsuit, but at worst it's a lawsuit fought between two insurance companies, which is far more preferable than "personally liable in some way for the death of x".
You probably can request the tenant do the work, but I'd caution against it. Part of being a landlord means hiring people to fix stuff. I'd also argue that if this is tripping, say, a circuit breaker, that also suggests something is not right in the electrical system, and it would be very easy for the family of the hypothetically electrocuted tenant to find an expert to testify to this.

Other questions I'd probably ask myself: Am I sure my home wiring is up to code? Completely, or are there any exceptions? Was the garbage disposal installed by a professional, or was it done by me? Was it actually installed according to the manufacturers instructions, or is it bodged in some way? These are the fun questions a lawyer would be asking in the event of an issue, so it's probably worth thinking about them beforehand.

Nitpick: Insurance companies usually do not sue each other. They swap evidence, talk about it for a bit (which could be anywhere from five minutes all the way up to several business days, depending on the process and the amount at stake), and then one of them writes the other a check. If that fails, they (presumably) go to private arbitration, which is still far cheaper than a lawsuit. As a private citizen, you do not have the benefit of this kind of ongoing business relationship with a counterparty, so you would end up in court.

@Kevin, that's fair! I know lawsuits between companies are pretty common, but I guess that's more to do with vast numbers of claims between them

For #1, manually turning a garbage disposal motor works in a way that prevents that from even being possible. You don't manually turn the motor by reaching into the disposal from above. You do it by sticking an Allen wrench (provided with the disposal) into a slot designed for the purpose on the outside bottom of the disposal, and rotating it. If you drop the Allen wrench, it just falls onto the bottom of the cabinet. The action is by design so trivially simple and easy that amateurs can do it safely just following an instruction manual, because the problem that it fixes is so common.
